# UIDatePicker repositioning to the bottom of the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I'm building a to-do app where user can select the reminder option. If reminder is enabled, then a UIDatePicker would be enabled. I created the main UI with storyboard. So my initial UI is like this

[image]

But after disabling and enabling again the reminder switch, the Datepicker placed on top of the view. I need to position it to the bottom of the view.

[image]

My ViewController code is like this

```
- (IBAction)isReminderSelected:(UISwitch *)sender {
    if([_reminderSetField isOn]){
    [_reminderSetField.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview: _reminderDatePicker];
}
else {
    [_reminderDatePicker removeFromSuperview];}
}
```

I created the main UI via storyboard. Then initialize the datepicker in the header file....

My *.h file

```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *reminderSetField;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *reminderDatePicker; 
  - (IBAction)isReminderSelected:(UISwitch *)sender;
```

Comment: What constraints do you have on the date pickers?

Comment: I don't have any constraint.

Comment: can you please upload the setup code of the date picker we not understand  from this code snippet

Comment: I created the main UI via storyboard. Then initialize the datepicker in the header file....

I added the header file part in the question.

Comment: If you didn't turn off auto layout, then it's on, and the system will add constraints for you -- they're often not what you want. You should add your own constraints.

Comment: you remove the date picker then create it again right? but if you don't used the autolayout why you used viewForBaselineLayout ?

Comment: Yes, I removed the DatePicker when the switch is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `y` position of the picker view like

```
float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - _reminderDatePicker.frame.size.height;

[_reminderDatePicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, _reminderDatePicker.frame.size.width, _reminderDatePicker.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Not working. Still I can get the DatePicked on the same place.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try like this

```
- (IBAction)isReminderSelected:(UISwitch *)sender {
    if([_reminderSetField isOn]){
        float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - _reminderDatePicker.frame.size.height;

        [_reminderDatePicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, _reminderDatePicker.frame.size.width, _reminderDatePicker.frame.size.height)];
[yourView addSubView:_reminderDatePicker];
}
else {
        [_reminderDatePicker removeFromSuperview];}
}
```